# Scoped services - is it the same copy per request? It feels like multiple copies are being used in my code

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a scoped service:

```
public class GetLatestStatus:IGetLatestStatus{
   private HttpClient _httpClient;
   private readonly int _status;

   public GetLatestStatus(HttpClient httpClient){
      _httpClient = httpClient;
      _date= GetStatusFromService(); 
   }

   public string GetStatus(){
      return _status;
   }

   private string GetStatusFromService(){
       Logger.Info($"Calling service...");
       var request = new HttpGetRequest{Url = "http://some.service/get/status"};
       var result = _httpClient.Get(request).Result;
       return result.Status;
   }
}
```

Here is how it is defined in the startup:

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
   services.AddScoped<IGetLatestStatus, GetLatestStatus>() 
           .AddHttpClient<IGetLatestStatus, GetLatestStatus>();

   services.AddTransient<ISomeClass1, SomeClass1>();
   services.AddTransient<ISomeClass2, SomeClass2>();
   services.AddTransient<ISomeClass3, SomeClass3>();
}
```

It is being used by three transient classes.

The intent of this class is that _status is defined only once, when the request comes in. Then it is stored throughout the lifecycle of the request.

Instead, it seems that GetStatusFromService() is being called three times, one per transient class, when the request first comes in.

How do I make this class work the way I intended? I thought that defining something as a Scoped Service means that there's only one copy for the lifecycle of the request. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Yes, there's only one instance. But that instance is used by three classes. If all the three classes are used in a request, they will all call the method. You could of course only run the request in `GetLatestStatus` once and return the result from cache afterwards.

Comment: @germi Why would they all call the method? it is called in the constructor of the scoped instance. I would expect it to work just like OP did

Comment: Yeah sorry, I overlooked that it's only called from the ctor. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL:DR**

It happens because you register `GetLatestStatus` like this after scoped registration `.AddHttpClient<IGetLatestStatus, GetLatestStatus>();`

So may create another class to store the status and register it as scoped. Then use the Http Configured service to reach the service from it

---

According to MSDN;

To configure the above structure, add HttpClientFactory in your application by installing the Microsoft.Extensions.Http NuGet package that includes the AddHttpClient() extension method for IServiceCollection. This extension method registers the DefaultHttpClientFactory to be used as a singleton for the interface IHttpClientFactory. **It defines a transient configuration** for the HttpMessageHandlerBuilder. This message handler (HttpMessageHandler object), taken from a pool, is used by the HttpClient returned from the factory.

Please check the link for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests